How to make SARIMAX predictions based on more recent portions of the data?
I am working with a time series that ranges from 2022 to 2024 at a weekly granularity. Although I am providing the entire dataset, as it is important for capturing seasonality, I want the predictions for the rest of the year and the beginning of 2025 to be based more on the recent portion of the data.
For example, Prophet has a function called changepoint_prior_scale that achieves exactly this. It controls the flexibility of the model in detecting changes in the trend.
Therefore, is there any analogous parameter or way to achieve this in SARIMAX?
